# 'react-router-dom' does not contain an export named 'useParams'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In App.js I have the following route:

```
<Route path="/Comp1/:catid">
    <Comp1 />
</Route>
```

This route can be called by clicking this link with a single parameter:

```
<Link to={'/Comp1/' + catid}>Comp1 </Link>
```

The parameter catid always has a certain value.

Comp1 is a component defined as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Comp1 extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const params = useParams();
        const { catid } = params.catid;
        console.log(catid);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello, I am class Comp1
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

But what is happening now is at runtime, I am getting the following debug output:

'react-router-dom' does not contain an export named 'useParams'

--edit--

Installed version of react-router-dom is 4.2.2.

Comment: Which version of react-router-dom do you have installed? v5 and v6 have significantly different APIs.

Comment: (And in any case, you can't use hooks with class components.)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a version issue. Also discussed in [this official issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/6944).

Solution: Make sure you are using `react-router-dom@>=5.1`, since that particular hook was introduced in [the 5.1 release](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0).

If you have trouble getting modules installed at a proper version, then is the perfect time to practice just that, especially since it is very likely going to happen again and again, if you don't.

[image]

Comment: I upgraded react-router-dom to version 5.1.0 now the error keeps away. But now it's saying 'Stateless function components cannot have refs.'

Comment: @Mobygo It sounds like you are working on outdated code or an outdated setup. In `react@16.8.0` introduced hooks to help with all that. You are looking for `useRef` and/or `forwardRef`.